# How to remove the address bar from a popup window

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

```
onClick="window.open('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.cart&product_id=<?php echo $product_id?
>&Itemid=18','mywindow','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350')"
```

Comment: Come on man, put a little effort into your question ...

Comment: The question has unbelievable 16k views. How's that even possible? There is not a single research effort, just copy and paste. These guys are from outer space.

Comment: @AlanMachado A billiion flies can't err.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer will always show the address bar, it isn't possible to remove it on a popup.  Some browsers will hide the address bar with the `location=no` flag, but IE doesn't.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> In Internet Explorer 7 and later, you cannot remove the address bar in Internet Zone windows, for security (anti-spoofing) reasons.

Popups should be avoided anyway, many visitors will have popup blocking software or the browser will simply block it. It would be better to consider something like a `<div>` overlay on the page which you could code manually, or use a ready made plugin such as jQuery UI Dialog or Lightbox.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the address bar follow the steps below

1) Select Tools in IE7 
2) Select Security Tab 
3) Choose Internet Zone and click on Custom level 
4) Scroll down till “Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars” 
5) Select "Disable" -> OK 
6) Restart IE7 and you are done.To disable the address bar follow the steps below